# Resultant Temperature

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Ok im not totally sure if this problem can be solved without the theories of physics; but here goes:

With three different unknown quantities x,y and z of the same kind of liquid of temperatures 9, 21, 38C respectively, it is found that when x, y, are mixed together the resultant temperature is 17C and when y and z are mixed together the resultant temperature is 28C. Find the resultant temperature if x and z were mixed.

Answer is 25.92 C

Construct equations:

```
9*m_1 + 21*m_2 = 17*(m_1+m_2)

21*m_2 + 38*m_3 = 28*(m_2+m_3)
```

Simplify equation 1

```
 9*m_1 + 21*m_2 = 17*(m_1+m_2) => m_2 = 2*m_1
```

Substitute m_2

```
21*(2)*m_1 + 38*m_3 = 28*((2)*m_1+m_3)
42*m_1 + 38*m_3 = 56*m_1 + 28*m_3 ; -28*m_1 on both sides
14*m_1 + 38*m_3 = 28*(m_1 + m_3)
```

my answer is 28... am i missing a physics formula?

Comment: `14*m_1 + 38*m_3 = 28*(m_1 + m_3)` means that the resultant temperature is 28C if the temperature of the first liquid was 14C and the third was 38C. The calculation is right but you answered another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the same logic you used earlier, you are asked to solve $9m_1+38m_3=T(m_1+m_3)$, where $T$ is the final temperature.  From equation 2, $10m_3=7m_2$, so $\frac 92 m_2+38\cdot \frac 7{10}m_2=T(\frac 12+\frac 7{10})m_2, T=311/12 \approx 25.917$ according to [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9%2F2%2B38*7%2F10%3Dx%281%2F2%2B7%2F10%29)

Answer (score 0):

If you write the balance equations, you have $$9x+21y=17(x+y)$$ $$21y+38z=28(y+z)$$ $$9x+38z=T(x+z)$$ Frm the first equation you have $y=2x$; from the second equation $z=\frac 7{10}y=\frac 75 x$. Plug in the last equation $$9x+38\frac 75 x=T(x+\frac 75 x)$$ that is to say $$\frac {311}5 x=\frac {12}5 x T$$ from which $$T=\frac{311}{12}\approx 25.9167$$